# Add header.ejs file inside the ejs-locals header block

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I don't know whether it is possible or not So Please give me a suggestion. My question is How to add(include) header.ejs inside the `ejs-locals` header block?

boilerplate.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>It's me</title>
    <%-scripts%>
    <%-stylesheets%>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <%-blocks.header%>
    </header>
    <section>
      <%-body -%>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <%-blocks.footer%>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.ejs

```
<% layout('boilerplate') -%>
<% script('foo.js') -%>
<% stylesheet('foo.css') -%>

<h1>I am the  template</h1>
<p class="better-than-dead">I'm red if foo.css was loaded.</p>
<p>Here are some muppets we know about:</p>

<% block('header', "<p>I'm in the header.</p>") -%>
<% block('footer', "<p>I'm in the footer.</p>") -%>
```

header.ejs

```
<p>I'm in the header</p>
```

In the above code(index.ejs), You can see header block has the HTML code.But there I would like to include the header.ejs.

Thanks.